# Unable To Replace A Block Minecraft Modding 1.16.5 Forge

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

Currently, I'm making a mod that adds extra bee items to the game. And now I want to make a item that polished things like diorite, andesite, granite, etc. As a tool.

But I can't seem to be able to replace a block when I right click it. I've looked threw a lot of posts and found nothing good. All of the answers are outdated.

So far I tried using `Block replaceBlock = Blocks.POLISHED_DIORITE;`and world.setBlock. But it just dose nothing. Here is my code:

```
package com.technowin.beeutil.item.custom;

import net.minecraft.block.AbstractBlock;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.BlockState;
import net.minecraft.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemUseContext;
import net.minecraft.util.ActionResultType;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Waxer extends Item {
    public Waxer(Properties properties) {
        super(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public ActionResultType onItemUseFirst(ItemStack stack, ItemUseContext context) {
        World world = context.getWorld();

        if(!world.isRemote) {
            PlayerEntity playerEntity = Objects.requireNonNull(context.getPlayer());
            BlockState clickedBlock = world.getBlockState(context.getPos());

            rightClickOnCertinBlockState(clickedBlock, context, playerEntity);
            stack.damageItem(1, playerEntity, player -> player.sendBreakAnimation(context.getHand()));
            
        }
        return super.onItemUseFirst(stack, context);
    }

    private void rightClickOnCertinBlockState(BlockState clickedBlock,
                                              ItemUseContext context, PlayerEntity playerEntity) {

        if(blockIsValidForWaxDio(clickedBlock)) {
            polishdioriteblock(playerEntity, context.getWorld(), context.getPos());
        }
        if(blockIsValidForWaxGra(clickedBlock)) {
            polishgraniteblock(playerEntity, context.getWorld(), context.getPos());
        }
    }

    private boolean blockIsValidForWaxDio(BlockState clickedBlock) {
        return clickedBlock.getBlock() == Blocks.DIORITE;
    }

    private boolean blockIsValidForWaxGra(BlockState clickedBlock) {
        return clickedBlock.getBlock() == Blocks.GRANITE;


    }

    private void polishdioriteblock(PlayerEntity playerEntity, World world, BlockPos pos) {
        Block replaceBlock = Blocks.POLISHED_DIORITE;
    }

    private void polishgraniteblock(PlayerEntity playerEntity, World world, BlockPos pos) {
        Block replaceBlock = Blocks.POLISHED_DIORITE;
    }
}
```

NOTE:

I am new to minecraft modding, this is my 2nd ever mod. And I am not a master at Java.

Comment: You claim to use the `world.setBlock()` method, but it never appears in your code.  This would seem to be the root of your problem.

Comment: I used it, but it just errored and said such a command dose not exist. Thats why its not in my code

Comment: Can you provide the line you tried that gave you an error?  My guess is that you haven't followed the method signature, which requires 3 arguments: a BlockPos, a BlockState, and an int.

Comment: I solved it. I needed to use world.setblockstate insted of world.setblock

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to use the method `world.setBlockState(...)`:

```
@Override
public ActionResultType onItemUseFirst(ItemStack stack, ItemUseContext context) {
    if (!context.getWorld().isRemote()) {
        World world = context.getWorld();
        BlockPos pos = context.getPos();
        BlockState state = world.getBlockState(pos);
        PlayerEntity playerEntity = Objects.requireNonNull(context.getPlayer());

        if (state.getBlock() == Blocks.DIORITE) {
            world.setBlockState(pos, Blocks.POLISHED_DIORITE.getDefaultState());
            stack.damageItem(1, playerEntity, player -> player.sendBreakAnimation(context.getHand()));
        } else if (state.getBlock() == Blocks.GRANITE) {
            world.setBlockState(pos, Blocks.POLISHED_GRANITE.getDefaultState());
            stack.damageItem(1, playerEntity, player -> player.sendBreakAnimation(context.getHand()));
        }
    }
    return super.onItemUseFirst(stack, context);
}
```